# npgsql error with entity framework 6

Tags: c#, postgresql, exception, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I'm trying to setup postgres db - entity framework application.
Database first approach.
I'm following a [tutorial](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/wiki/Visual-Studio-Design-Time-Support---DDEX-Provider)
I have added new data connection to visual studio, created new project (WF), built it, nugetted npgsql and now i'm trying to add new item->ado.net entity data model->generate from database and i get an exception:

[image: exception]

Comment: Which EF version (look in packages.config) ?

Comment: EF6 like in title, tutorial and packages.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Npgsql" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Npgsql.EntityFramework" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>

Comment: Tried EF 6.1.2. Reopen and rebuild solution and no luck. The same error appears.